# Wikipedia says for Generics - "One version of the class or function is compiled, works for all type parameters. "

Tags: java

How does Java do this? If there are not multiple Classes being created, then how does it support multiple Typed instantiations of the Generic class?
Until now I used to believe that it is like C++, but now i am totally confused.
Can't figure out how Java pulls this off?

-Ajay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since only reference types can be used as generic type arguments in Java, and all pointers are the same size, the same byte code can be used.

As for type safety, generics in Java a compile/link-time only. That is, during compilation generic types are replaced by their *erasure*. The erasure of a type variable `T` is its lower bound (or `Object`, if it doesn't have one). For instance,

```
class Complex<N extends Number> {
    N real;
    N imag;
}
```

becomes

```
class Complex {
    Number real;
    Number imag;
}
```

as far as byte code is concerned.

Needless to say that is not pretty and causes numerous limitations. The most obvious one is that

```
new N();
```

does not compile, because the runtime does not know the type N stands for and hence can't instiate the type. Similarly,

```
(N) n
```

will compile, but unlike an ordinary cast in Java, will not be checked at runtime. An incorrect cast can therefore cause a variable to hold an object of the wrong type. This is called heap pollution. To ensure (a weaker form of) type safety, the compiler will introduce casts into calling code. For instance,

```
boolean right(Complex<Integer> c) {
    return c.real > 0;
}
```

will become

```
boolean right(Complex c) {
    return ((Integer) c.real) > 0;
}
```

To sum things up, the generics implementation in Java is not pretty, especially compared to the .NET one. The things we have to live with for the sake of backwards compatibility ...

Answer (score 6):

This is due to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). Java's generics are primarily a compile-time feature. All generic types are, at runtime, <s>`Object`s</s> replaced with their lower bound.

---

Thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16883/michael-borgwardt) for the correction:

> Generics are not strictly a compile-time feature. If a class, method or field has a generic type with a concrete type parameter specified, this information will be present at runtime and is available via reflection.

To elaborate:

> When runtime inspecting a parameterizable type itself, like `java.util.List`, there is no way of knowing what type is has been parameterized to. This makes sense since the type can be parameterized to all kinds of types in the same application. But, when you inspect the **method or field** that declares the use of a parameterized type, you can see at runtime what type the paramerizable type was parameterized to. In short:
>
> You cannot see on a type itself what type it is parameterized to a runtime, but you can see it in fields and methods where it is used and parameterized. Its concrete parameterizations in other words.

[Source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html)

Comment: +1. And that doesn't go for Java alone. I think most (compiled) languages work that way.

Comment: @GolezTrol not always C++ and D (both "system level" compiled languages) templates are newly compiled for each instance this adds code bloat but increases runtime performance and flexibility

Comment: Generics are not strictly a compile-time feature. If a class, method or field has a generic type with a concrete type parameter specified, this information will be present at runtime and is available via reflection.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I need to bone up on my Java generics internals.

Comment: Well, the type information of a parameterized *instance* is indeed lost completely after compilation. What is available through Reflection is the fact that a class or method was declared with type parameters and what the bounding types are. But this information would be available anyway to the implementation since it is stated in the declaration. In short: The potentially useful part of the type information is gone entirely but Refection can tell you what you already knew.

Comment: @x4j: That summary is inaccurate. The reflection api does not only expose the bounds of the type parameters, but also the actual type expression as declared in the source code, i.e. if a field is declared of type `List<Integer>`, we can discover that the field will hold a `List<Integer>`. Likewise, the type expression in a class declaration can be queried using reflection, which allows a generic superclass to infer its type parameters if the instance's runtime class is not-generic. See http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html for a practical application of this technique.

Answer (score 0):

good question. The genetic information is not kept during runtime. E.g if you have this code

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();    // this is a list of apples
```

But in runtime it becomes :

```
List apples = new ArrayList();    // this is how it looks in runtime
```